# how to add a text for the selected text on a combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a windows application with a combobox.
Here is my code:

```
Dim TitleVList As New List(Of TitleV_List)


    con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    'Fill the UOM Drop Down with all System UOM
    sql = "Select ID, Full_Name FROM cts_TitleV_Leads WHERE IsActive = 1"
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader




    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        While dr.Read

            TitleVList.Add(New TitleV_List(dr("Full_Name"), dr("ID")))

        End While
    End If

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
        dr.Close()
    End If




    ddlpropTitleVlist.DataSource = TitleVList

    ddlpropTitleVlist.DisplayMember = "Full_Name"
    ddlpropTitleVlist.ValueMember = "ID"
```

What I would like is that when the combobox is displayed for the first time it shows "Select Item" as the selected text but when they click on the dropdown arrow "Select Item" does NOT show in the list.
I have tried

ddlpropTitleVlist.SelectedText = "Select Item"

ddlpropTitleVlist.Text = "Select Item"

but when the screen shows it show does not show "Select Item" it shows the first name in the list.
I do have a tabcontrol and I am using TabControl_DrawItem because my tabs are horizontal. I don't know if that has to do with this not working.

Please help.

Thank you
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        ComboBox1.Text = "Select Item"
    End If
End Sub
```

The idea is that, at design time, you can add whatever options you want in your ComboBox items collection. At run time, in the Form.Activated event (Form.Load should work, too) the `SelectedIndex` property of the ComboBox is set to -1. Inside the ComboBox's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, if the index is -1, set the `Text` property to the placeholder text. Note that in order to get this to work (at least on my system), I had to set `SelectedIndex` to zero before setting it to -1.